# Wordpress: Custom Post Type with different base URL from Standard Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I created a custom post type called Products alongside by blog. My blog Archive URL is

```
www.mywebsite.com/blog
```

and the blog posts looks like

```
www.mywebsite.com/blog/postName.
```

My Products Custom Post Type URL looks like

```
www.mywebsite.com/blog/products.
```

I want would like to remove the blog directory from the url and make it look just like

```
www.mywebsite.com/products/productName
```

I can do this by removing the `/blog/%postname%` from my permalinks in Wordpress, but then my blog posts look like: `www.mywebsite.com/postName`, without the blog directory.

How do I give my custom post types a clean URL without the blog directory?

Comment: Is `/blog/` the home page / root URL of your WP site?

Comment: @rnevius I created a page called blog and set it up under Settings -> Reading -> A Static Page -> Post Page. My home page is a static page that I created called Home.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps you. Do something like that --

```
$labels      = array(
                'name'               => $plural_title,
                'singular_name'      => $title,
                'add_new'            => __( 'Add New', 'adeq' ),
                'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New', 'adeq' ) .' '. $title,
                'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit', 'adeq' ) .' '. $title,
                'new_item'           => __( 'New', 'adeq' ) .' '. $title,
                'all_items'          => __( 'All', 'adeq' ) .' '. $plural_title,
                'view_item'          => __( 'View', 'adeq' ) .' '. $title,
                'search_items'       => __( 'Search', 'adeq' ) .' '. $plural_title,
                'not_found'          => $plural_title . __( ' not found', 'adeq' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => $plural_title . __( ' not found in Trash', 'adeq' ),
                'parent_item_colon'  => '',
                'menu_name'          => $plural_title
                );

            if ( !empty( $args['labels_override'] ) ) {
                $labels = wp_parse_args( $args['labels_override'], $labels );
            }

            $defaults = array(
                'labels'             => $labels,
                'public'             => true,
                'publicly_queryable' => true,
                'show_ui'            => true,
                'show_in_menu'       => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus'  => true,
                'query_var'          => true,
                'has_archive'        => true,
                'hierarchical'       => false,
                'menu_position'      => null,
                'menu_icon'          => null,
                'supports'           => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor' )
                );

            $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
            $this->post_types[ $post_type ] = $args;
        }
    }
```

[Your Permalink will show like --](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfwlL.png)